# create a database in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a question: How can I create a database in mysql if I'm not root? I know that to create a database a user must have create database privilege but I don't know how to grant that privilege from root. Could you help me with specific commands? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-database.html Try reading that :) Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Give a privilege to user like this.

```
grant all on dba.* to 'wim'@'localhost';
```